# Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp and Microsoft.CodeAnalysis - The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, .net-core, lint, .net-6.0

So the problem is, I have `.NET 6`. Then I do `dotnet restore`. After that, I want to do `dotnet format -v diag --report ./editor-report.json --verify-no-changes  example.sln`.

But after formatting I got that error:

```
 Analysis complete in 2554ms.
Unhandled exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Then I think maybe I can just install that dependencies. But I can't.

```
dotnet tool install --global Microsoft.CodeAnalysis
/tmp/sf1h1yl0.gli/restore.csproj : error NU1212: Invalid project-package combination for Microsoft.CodeAnalysis 4.1.0. DotnetToolReference project style can only contain references of the DotnetTool type 
The tool package could not be restored.
```

How can I fix it? By the way the `.NET 5` scan is doing well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed this same issue in GitHub Actions, but wasn't able to reproduce locally.

It seems, according to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/format/issues/1500), that it's related to having the version `6.0.200` of the SDK installed on your machine. The suggestions in that thread are to either rename `6.0.200` or uninstall it entirely, but I haven't found another workaround.

Comment: Thank you, downgrade to SDK 6.0.100 helped.